# Kendo Asp.net mvc muliple grids wrong methods are firing

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have an asp.net mvc page and it has multiple grids. I am not able to figure out why I am having a problem. Can you please look at my code and suggest what I am doing wrong?

Right now I have two grids in the View but the methods are not firing properly. Sometimes the create method is fired two times or more and sometimes the update method is firing a create method. I am returning the ID but its not working.

I have to add few more grids in the View. Is there any problem with the MVC or what?

```
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
 
  <%: Html.Kendo().Grid<SSTS.Models.RegistrationEntryViewModel>()
        .Name("grid")
        .Columns(columns =>
        {
            columns.Bound(p => p.SchoolTransactionID);
            columns.Bound(p => p.RegisterNo).Width(100);
            columns.Bound(p => p.TransDate).Width(100);
            columns.Bound(p => p.StudentNumber).Width(100);
            columns.Bound(p => p.SurName).Width(100);
            columns.Bound(p => p.GivenName).Width(100);
            columns.Bound(p => p.ReasonCode).Width(100);
            columns.Bound(p => p.ReasonCodeDescription).Width(100);
            columns.Bound(p => p.DateStartedSchoool).Width(100);
            columns.Bound(p => p.DateLeftSchool).Width(100);
 
            columns.Command(command => { command.Edit(); command.Destroy(); }).Width(172);
        })
        .ToolBar(toolbar => toolbar.Create())
        .Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.InLine))
        .Pageable()
        .Sortable()
        .Scrollable()
        .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "height:430px;" })
        .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
            .Ajax()
            .PageSize(20)
            .Events(events => events.Error("error_handler"))
            .Model(model => model.Id(p => p.SchoolTransactionID))
                        .Create(update => update.Action("RegistrationEntry_Create", "StudentTransaction"))
                        .Read(read => read.Action("RegistrationEntry_Read", "StudentTransaction"))
                        .Update(update => update.Action("RegistrationEntry_Update", "StudentTransaction"))
                        .Destroy(update => update.Action("RegistrationEntry_Destroy", "StudentTransaction"))
        )
    %>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function error_handler(e) {
            if (e.errors) {
                var message = "Errors:\n";
                $.each(e.errors, function (key, value) {
                    if ('errors' in value) {
                        $.each(value.errors, function () {
                            message += this + "\n";
                        });
                    }
                });
                alert(message);
            }
        }
 
        function error_handler2(e) {
            if (e.errors) {
                var message = "Errors:\n";
                $.each(e.errors, function (key, value) {
                    if ('errors' in value) {
                        $.each(value.errors, function () {
                            message += this + "\n";
                        });
                    }
                });
                alert(message);
            }
        }
        function error_handler2(e) {
            if (e.errors) {
                var message = "Errors:\n";
                $.each(e.errors, function (key, value) {
                    if ('errors' in value) {
                        $.each(value.errors, function () {
                            message += this + "\n";
                        });
                    }
                });
                alert(message);
            }
        }
    </script>
 
 
     <%: Html.Kendo().Grid<SSTS.Models.StudentBehaviourEntry>()
        .Name("grid2")
        .Columns(columns =>
        {
            columns.Bound(p => p.StudentBehaviourID);
            columns.Bound(p => p.ActionPerformedNumber).Width(100);
            columns.Bound(p => p.StudentNumber).Width(100);
            columns.Bound(p => p.SurName).Width(100);
             columns.Bound(p => p.GivenName).Width(100);
            columns.Bound(p => p.BreachCategory).Width(100);
            columns.Bound(p => p.BriefDescription).Width(100);
            columns.Bound(p => p.ActionTaken).Width(100);
            columns.Bound(p => p.RespondedDate).Width(100);
            columns.Bound(p => p.RespondedTime).Width(100);
            columns.Bound(p => p.SuspensionStartDate).Width(100);
            columns.Bound(p => p.SuspensionFinishDate).Width(100);
            columns.Bound(p => p.Remarks).Width(100);
 
            columns.Command(command => { command.Edit(); command.Destroy(); }).Width(172);
        })
        .ToolBar(toolbar => toolbar.Create())
        .Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.InLine))
        .Pageable()
        .Sortable()
        .Scrollable()
        .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "height:430px;" })
        .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
            .Ajax()
            .PageSize(20)
                     .Events(events => events.Error("error_handler2"))
            .Model(model => model.Id(p => p.StudentBehaviourID))
                              .Create(update => update.Action("Behaviour_Create", "StudentTransaction"))
                              .Read(read => read.Action("Behaviour_Read", "StudentTransaction"))
                              .Update(update => update.Action("Behaviour_Update", "StudentTransaction"))
                              .Destroy(update => update.Action("Behaviour_Destroy", "StudentTransaction"))
        )
    %>
   
   
  
 
</asp:Content>
```

Comment: Why do you have two JS functions with the same name (`error_handler2`)? Is that the function that fires twice?

Comment: yea i have removed it but still no success

Comment: Which function/method is triggered twice? You are not really giving us enough information...

Comment: Are you returning the object created by `RegistrationEntry_Create()` in your controller? If you aren't, then that's why you keep getting multiple ajax calls. Kendo expects you to return the object, not just the Id. http://docs.kendoui.com/api/framework/datasource#configuration-transport.create

Comment: yes i am returning RegistrationEntry_Create() and sometimes create method is firing multiple times the first grid works fine in most of the time but the second grid ha problems sometimes read method doesnot fire and when i click the create button then read button fires adding record fires multiple times and update fires the create method is it a version problem or asp.net mvc has some issues? i am using a linq to sql